# How to display my array using JOptionPane.showMessageDialog

Tags: java, arrays, joptionpane

I have this code

---

=======

```
int row = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter number of rows");
int col = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter number of columns");
int[][] sum = new int[row][col];
int x,y;
int result;
for(x=0;x<row;x++) {
for (y=0;x<col;y++) {
int inpx = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Value for " + x + "," + y);
result = result + inpx
```

My problem is how can I display the sum of each value in row I entered please help

Comment: You _might_ want to be somewhat more specific, i.e. _where_ do you want to display that? In what form (table, list, whatever)?

Comment: You have declared 2 dimensional array for sum which is not required. It can be 1 dimensional array and you can iterate through each item to sum them in a row.

Comment: Are you trying to display the cumulative sum along each row?!  For example,  
`  1  2  3  4  5` would display as  
`  1  3  6 10 15`  
Do you want to display the sums in showInputDialog boxes?

Comment: Those row and col are the values for rows and columns which I put it in input dialog cause it's depends on the user on how much he want and my problem is if I have values on those rows and columns I just need to show the sum of the row example. If I have a value of 2 for row  my message box should display this Row(0)=6, row(1)=8

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean with your question, but if you want to see the sum of the row and column you can use this

```
    int row = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter row"));
    int col = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter column"));
    int[][] sum = new int[row][col];

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Result: "+ (i + j));
        }
    }
```

If you only want to display a message, use showMessageDialog, rather than showInputDialog

You can also tweak the loop to work with the sum array, if that's what you want. Although in my example it would be useless as they have no values.

**Edit**:

```
  int[][] sum = new int[5][5];

    for (int i = 0; i < sum.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < sum[i].length; j++) {
            sum[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Enter value for (" + i + "," + j + ")"));
        }
    }

    int row = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter row"));
    int col = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter column"));
    int value = sum[row][col];
    int row2 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter second row"));
    int col2 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter second column"));
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, String.format("(%d,%d)[%d] * (%d,%d)[%d] = %d", row, col, sum[row][col], row2, col2, sum[row2][col2], value * sum[row2][col2]));
```

Comment: I'm sorry I'm really poor at speaking english. But what I mean is when I enter some values to the row and column then the input dialog will appear and I will put some values for that like example. (0,0)=1,(0,1)=2,(1,0)=3,(1,1)=4 is it possible that I can only get the sum of the row like for row (0,0)(0,1)=3 ,row(1,0)(1,1)=7

Comment: I have edited my answer, look towards the bottom and you will see another snippet. Is that closer to what you're after? It allows you to define a 5*5 2d array, populate the array with values from an input box, and then allows you to choose 2 positions in the 2d array, they are then multiplied together to give you the answer.